# Visio vba Connecting a dynamic connector to a connection point

Tags: vba, visio

I'm having some troubles connecting a linked dynamic connector which actually connects to a pre-defined connection point instead of just connection to the top.

My master has some text boxes at the left side and some at the right side. When I auto connect to those text boxes they all connect fine except the first and last one. Instead of connecting to the side like the others they connect to the top and bottom  in the middle of the box which ruins the visual effect. Even though there is a connection point defined at the side.

I have been looking at using GlueTo to connect manually to the connection point but I can't figure out how to adress the connection point.

```
Set vsoConnectorShape = ActiveDocument.Masters.ItemU("Dynamic connector")
Set BoxShape = ActivePage.Shapes(i)
Set DevShape = ActivePage.Shapes(j)

NewRow = DevShape.AddRow(visSectionConnectionPts, visRowLast, visTagDefault)
DevShape.CellsSRC(visSectionConnectionPts, NewRow, visX).Formula = "Width*0"
DevShape.CellsSRC(visSectionConnectionPts, NewRow, visY).Formula = "Height*0.5"

DevShape.AutoConnect BoxShape, visAutoConnectDirLeft, vsoConnectorShape
```

So my actual question would be how do i connect to a connection point instead of the shape itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can glue the `.Cells("BeginX")` or `.Cells("EndX")` of a connector

1. either to the nearest connector of a shape: `Shape.Cells("PinX")`
2. or to a selected connector: `Shape.CellsSRC(visSectionConnectionPts, row, column)`

---

- The number of available connection points depends on your shape type
- If you click the shape and open its ShapeSheet by right mouseclick, you'll find a section "Connection Points". Each row of this table represents one connection point - click on the row in the table and see which one is selected in your drawing.
  Use the row number starting with 0 for `CellSRC`
  The column number is not relevant and can be 0 or 1 = visCnnctX or visCnnctY
- Alternatively just catch a manual connection with the macro recorder
  and search in the code for e. g.
  `CellSRC(7, 0, 0)`  7 = visSectionConnectionPts, 0 = 1st connection point, 0

---

```
Dim myConnector As Visio.Shape

' drop it somewhere
Set myConnector = ActiveWindow.Page.Drop(Application.ConnectorToolDataObject, 1, 10)

' connect it to the nearest connection point of a shape (varies if you drag)
myConnector.Cells("BeginX").GlueTo BoxShape.Cells("PinX")

' connect it a fixed connection point (example if shape has 4 points)
myconnector.Cells("BeginX").GlueTo _
    Boxshape.CellsSRC(visSectionConnectionPts, 0, 0)  ' left                  
' .CellsSRC(visSectionConnectionPts, 1, 0)  ' right
' .CellsSRC(visSectionConnectionPts, 2, 0)  ' top
' .CellsSRC(visSectionConnectionPts, 3, 0)  ' bottom
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Sadly i'm still getting the same results. The top field always gets connected to in the top middle instead of the left middle where i put my connection point...